# Visual studio highlights asp.net tags as hyperlinks

Tags: visual-studio

As you can see from the screenshot, vs2008 thinks asp tags are hyperlinks. I have reset all the settings on it but the issue is still there. I have tried on different projects and the same issue is present. I have moved the projects to another visual studio installation and problem has gone until I move them back.

Any one knows why this happens?

[alt text http://img12.imageshack.us/img12/9033/20090531191305.png](http://img12.imageshack.us/img12/9033/20090531191305.png)

http://img12.imageshack.us/img12/9033/20090531191305.png

Comment: Link posted seems to be broken to me. Can you check if it is correct.

Comment: opens fine on my browser http://img12.imageshack.us/img12/9033/20090531191305.png

Comment: weird! have not seen that before...

Comment: **my guess is that when it sees <asp: tag it thinks it is a href**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it happen for tags without an `asp:` prefix.

e.g. Can you create a UserControl, and drag that in and give it a different tag prefix

```
<cc1:MyCustomControl />
```

If not, then it sounds like something has gotten set on your system that treats `asp` as a protocol :(

But to be honest, I'm at a complete loss as to why this might happen.

Comment: you were right! i have used an sqlite frontend called sqliteplus and it has registered asp Enabled Pluggable Protocol Handler HTML Scripting Pages Pluggable Protocol Handler C:\Program Files\Common Files\EzTools\hsppp.dll HTML Scripting Pages Pluggable Protocol for running ASP pages in IE EzTools Software 24/05/2009 20:48:40

Comment: infact that crap ruined my registry by adding rndom protocols like  zip x-zip.

Thanks for your time

Comment: I was taking a shot in the dark, but that sounds like a really bloody nasty behaviour :(

Answer (score 0):

Must say it is strange. Although I am clueless, I will still try.

Are those real hyperlinks or just underlined text? If underlined text, then you can change the settings (since you have mentioned about resetting the setting, this won't work). If they are real hyperlinks, I am stumped.

Comment: as soon as i drop an asp.net control to the page VS underlines it and treats it like a hyperlink. when you mouse over in code view it tells you use ctrl+click to follwo the hyperlink. I clicked one and in the url of exploerer i got 

"asp:////ListView%20ID="TopVideosList"%20runat="server"%20EnableViewState="false"

I must add, tags works fine and does their jobs.